Is it true that if two functions have a finite number of linearly independent derivatives, then so do their sum and product?
I am trying to prove that $Q$ has a finite number of linearly independent derivatives if and only if $Q$ is a combination of functions of the form $\lambda,\lambda x^c ,\lambda e^{cx},\lambda \cos cx,\lambda  \sin cx$. I am able to prove the forward implication but the backward one eludes me.
My current strategy is to prove first that each of the functions mentioned above has a finite number of linearly independent derivatives (fairly easy to do) and then (provided the statement is true) prove that the sum and product of any function with linearly independent derivatives  also has linearly indepedent derivitaves.
Is the latter statement even true? If not, I request a counterexample, and if so, I would appreciate any hints in going about proving this.

If there's even a single linear relation among a function and its derivatives, doesn't that already imply the desired statement, just based on the theory of constant-coefficient differential equations?

@GregMartin If there exists a linear relation among $f$ and its derivatives, and another among $g$ and its derivatives, does there exist one among $f+g$ and its derivatives?

what do you mean by "combination"? How is $cos(sin(x))$ written as a combination of those functions?

@Exodd I meant combination by addition and multiplication

@VulgarMechanick To clarify, I was suggesting a strategy for the original problem in the first sentence, not for the proposed attempt using sums and products.

@GregMartin Apologies, you were right. I can get the backward implication by this as well (via annhilators)
